# Solving a differential equation (Rocket Velocity)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to calculate the velocity of a rocket, with changing gravity as altitude increases. This is where I am currently, $$\frac{-M*9.81}{(1+\frac{h}{Re})^2}+R(V{e})=M\frac{dv}{dt}$$

Where R is the Rate of burning fuel, i.e $\frac{dM}{dt}$,

M is the instantaneous Mass, i.e= $M_0 - Rt$,

h is the distance between the centre of earth and rocket,

$V{e}$ is the exhaustion velocity, $\therefore$ $R*V{e}=Thrust$.

Assuming my rocket goes vertically, I can replace h by $v*t$.
I am however stuck after this. My ultimate aim would be to solve for v, and then once I have this, add drag as well.

Can someone please help? 
Thank you!

Comment: Add a few words about the quantity $Re$. Be adviced that the height of the rocket above sealevel will not grow linearly with time as the rocket accelerates. It is extremely likely that a closed form solution can not be found or will be useless. You must be prepared to solve the differential equation numerically.

Comment: Yes, I know. However, how do I actually get to a solution? Where do I start with this?

Comment: Thank you very much @CarlChristian

Comment: @Cyril I used an equation which was similar to the rocket equation with changing velocities, and also posted a question. There is an answer by Mariusz Iwaniuk which works: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2676206/383527